# How to get ethernet adapter name in a variable having link/ether using perl script?

Tags: perl

Using perl script I want to find the name of ethernet adapter which are having specific string "link/ether" when we do "ip/addr".
I want to store them in a variable.
like:-

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
link/ether 00:21:28:d6:1f:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
link/ether 00:21:28:d6:1f:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
link/ether 00:21:28:d6:1f:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: ab0:  <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
link/band 00:21:28:d6:1f:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

from above out should output the following:-

```
eth1
eth2
eth3
```

like storing in a variable and running in loop.
This is what I was trying but not working properly:-

```
my $last="";
my @results = `ip addr`;
my $adap="";
my $flag=0;
foreach my $line (@results)
{
if (($line =~ /ether/))
{
   $adap = substr($last,3,7);
   chomp($adap);
   $str = $adap;
   $flag=1;
}
}
print $adap;
```

Comment: What is in `$last`? You don't show that variable being set. Did you mean `$line`?

Comment: @DaveCross- Updated the code above

Comment: Ok. Now you're trying to take a `substr()` of an empty string. I'm pretty sure that should be `substr($line, 3, 7)`.

Comment: @DaveCross - was doing "$last = $line;" at end , basic idea is to grep interface name containing "link/ether"

Comment: I'm not sure how I was supposed to guess that :-) I can only give advice based on the code you show me. Nevertheless, I think that if you look at `$line` rather than `$last`, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
my @results = 
    map { /^ \d+ : \s+ ( eth \d+ ) :/xa; $1 }
    grep { /ether/ } 
    `ip addr`;

print @results;
```

This takes the list returned by `` `ip addr` `` removes any line not containing ether  `grep { /ether/ }` then captures the part of the string containing `eth` followed by 1 or more digits.

The `x` on the end of the regex allows embedded white space and the a limits `\d` to just ascii digits.

You don't need to chomp the lines as you want the line endings when you print the list back out.

Comment: perl getin.pl 
Bareword found where operator expected at getin.pl line 3, near "/^ \d+ : \s+ ( eth \d+ ) :/xa"
 (Missing operator before a?)
syntax error at getin.pl line 3, near "/^ \d+ : \s+ ( eth \d+ ) :/xa"
Execution of getin.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Ah ok you are using an older version of Perl. Remove the `a` in `/xa` or get a newer version of Perl

Answer (score 0):

It can work like below and just store output in @array:-

```
ip -o addr show | grep "ether"  | awk -F': ' '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think this does what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Get the results from "ip addr". Store in @results.
my @results = `ip addr`;

# Variable to store the previous line
my $prev_line;

foreach my $line (@results) {
   # If the current line matches...
   if ($line =~ m|link/ether|) {
      # ... the extract the adapter name from the previous line
      my ($adap) = $prev_line =~ /: (\w+):/;
      print "$adap\n";
   }
   # Store the current line (which becomes the previous line).
   $prev_line = $line;
 }
```

For future reference, it's really helpful if you give us actual code that exhibits the behaviour you're asking about.